# Spread operator and the iterator protocol

Tags: javascript

I stumble upon this example about spread operators and tried to understand what's going on here:

```
let str = 'helloworld';
let first, rest;

[first, ...rest] = [...str];
console.log(first); // "h"
console.log(rest);  // ["e", "l", "l", "o", "w", "o", "r", "l", "d"]
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I read about the spread operator and how it implemented the iterator protocol and this is how I interpret it:

```
let str = 'helloworld';
let first, rest = [];
let itStr = str[Symbol.iterator]();

first = itStr.next().value;

while (val = itStr.next()) {
  if (val.done) {
    break;
  }
  rest.push(val.value);
};
console.log(first); // "h"
console.log(rest);  // ["e", "l", "l", "o", "w", "o", "r", "l", "d"]
```